# Liquibase with Postgres, changelog parameters are not replaced

Tags: oracle, postgresql, properties, liquibase, placeholder

I'm using liquibase with oracle and postgres and I would like to use the changeLog properties to customize the elements of the changeSets that are different in the two databases.

I'm using the example from https://www.liquibase.org/documentation/changelog_parameters.html.

Here is my db-changelog.xml

```
<databaseChangeLog
        xmlns="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xmlns:ext="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog-ext"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/dbchangelog-2.0.xsd
        http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog-ext http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/dbchangelog-ext.xsd">

    <property name="table.name" value="table_O" dbms="oracle"/>
    <property name="table.name" value="table_P" dbms="postgres"/>

    <property name="column1.name" value="column1_O" dbms="oracle"/>
    <property name="column1.name" value="column1_P" dbms="postgres"/>

    <property name="column2.name" value="column2_O" dbms="oracle"/>
    <property name="column2.name" value="column2_P" dbms="postgres"/>

    <property name="clob.type" value="blob" dbms="oracle"/>
    <property name="clob.type" value="bytea" dbms="postgres"/>

    <changeSet id="1" author="joe">
         <createTable tableName="${table.name}">
             <column name="id" type="int"/>
             <column name="${column1.name}" type="${clob.type}"/>
             <column name="${column2.name}" type="int"/>
         </createTable>
    </changeSet>
</databaseChangeLog>
```

The command

```
$ liquibase --driver=oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver \
            --classpath=ojdbc8-18.3.0.0.jar \
            --changeLogFile=db.changelog.test.xml \
            --url=jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521/my_db \
            --username=my_user \
            --password=my_pwd \
            --logLevel debug updateSQL > simple_changeLog_ORACLE.sql
```

works fine and I obtain the changelog for oracle, but the command

```
$ liquibase --driver=org.postgresql.Driver \
            --classpath=postgresql-42.2.5.jar \
            --changeLogFile=db.changelog.test.xml \
            --url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:15432/my_db \
            --username=my_user \
            --password=my_pwd \
            --logLevel debug updateSQL > simple_changeLog_POSTGRES.sql
```

fails with following exception

```
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1
        at liquibase.datatype.DataTypeFactory.fromDescription(DataTypeFactory.java:251)
        at liquibase.change.core.CreateTableChange.generateStatements(CreateTableChange.java:70)
        at liquibase.change.AbstractChange.generateStatementsVolatile(AbstractChange.java:287)
        at liquibase.change.AbstractChange.warn(AbstractChange.java:358)
        at liquibase.changelog.visitor.ValidatingVisitor.visit(ValidatingVisitor.java:110)
        at liquibase.changelog.ChangeLogIterator.run(ChangeLogIterator.java:83)
        at liquibase.changelog.DatabaseChangeLog.validate(DatabaseChangeLog.java:284)
        at liquibase.Liquibase.update(Liquibase.java:198)
        at liquibase.Liquibase.update(Liquibase.java:274)
        at liquibase.Liquibase.update(Liquibase.java:251)
        at liquibase.integration.commandline.Main.doMigration(Main.java:1433)
        at liquibase.integration.commandline.Main.run(Main.java:229)
        at liquibase.integration.commandline.Main.main(Main.java:143)
```

The option --logLevel debug shows a difference in the parsed changeSet.

The oracle one is

```
17:59:43.184 DEBUG [liquibase.util.MD5Util]: Computed checksum for createTable:[
    columns=[
        [
            name="id"
            type="int"
        ],
        [
            name="column1_O"
            type="blob"
        ],
        [
            name="column2_O"
            type="int"
        ]
    ]
    tableName="table_O"
] as 836321c599b350ca366cc6ea3bde3890
```

while the postgres one is

```
17:51:55.864 DEBUG [liquibase.util.MD5Util]: Computed checksum for createTable:[
    columns=[
        [
            name="id"
            type="int"
        ],
        [
            name="${column1.name}"
            type="${clob.type}"
        ],
        [
            name="${column2.name}"
            type="int"
        ]
    ]
    tableName="${table.name}"
] as 71476a8361010689730a8bf91f8d7115
```

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the only issue is that the value to use for postgres is `postgresql` rather than just `postgres`.

The list of database names is at https://www.liquibase.org/databases.html